# Fullscreen switching in all application

Tags: android, togglebutton, android-fullscreen, android-togglebutton

In my previous post [Fullscreen switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169570/fullscreen-switching][1]) i've try the next code:

```
if (isChecked)
            {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        else
            {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
```

and it's work, but for only one activity. How can i do it for all application?

Answer (score 0):

create an `Activity` class that all the other classes `extends` it. for example

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected abstract boolean toggleFullScreen();

    @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (toggleFullScreen()) {
            //fullScreen
        }
    }
}
```

now instead of extending `AppCompatActivity` in your other `Activity` extends the `BaseActivity`

Answer (score 0):

Always do your universal initialization under Application class.

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();       
        onActivityLifecycleCallback();

    }

    private void onActivityLifecycleCallback() {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

           @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 if (isChecked)
            {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        else
            {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
            }


        });
    }

}
```

or

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```